# codeigniter site "page not found" error on wamp server

Tags: codeigniter-2

The requested URL /myapp/welcome/login was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
codeigniter not found my site on local host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your site directory, if it has a .htaccess you need to activate mod_rewrite on your wamp server.

For this follow this picture and open httpd.conf file, search just "rewrite" and remove "#" from start of this. save your file and restart your server by clicking "Restart All Services".

[image]

[image]